# How to override the deferred binding configuration of a inherit gwt module

Tags: gwt, inheritance

is it possible to override the deferred binding configuration of a inherit module?

Here is a example:

In the module, I want to use, a deferred binding is declared as follows `moduleA.gwt.xml`:

```
<replace-with class="A1Impl">
    <when-type-is class="A"/>
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="A2Impl">
    <when-type-is class="A"/>
    <when-property-is name="p" value="1"/>
</replace-with>
```

The declaration says: Use `A1Impl` class as default and `A2Impl` class, if property `p` has the value `1`.

Now, in my app I want to use that module and want `P` to be `1` (because this controls the above shown, but also a lot of other deferred binding configurations) `mymodule.gwt.xml`:

```
<inherits name='moduleA'/>
<set-property name="p" value="1" />
```

But additionally I want to override the deferred binding configuration of the inherit module to use my own implementation of `A`. I tried something like this in my module, but it didn't work:

```
<replace-with class="B1Impl">
    <when-type-is class="A"/>
    <when-property-is name="p" value="1"/>
</replace-with>
```

It should say something like this: Do not use `A2Impl` (declared in inherit module) if property `p` has the value `1` but use my own implementation `B1Impl` instead.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, you can redefine any rebind rules that have already been set. Simply `inherit` the module you are changing, then make your changes after that rebind rule.

```
<inherits name="package.to.ModuleA" />
<set-property name="p" value="1" />
```

With the code above, p is always 1, so setting specific rules about what p will be is a little bit silly. Unless p is ever able to be something other than 1, you really don't even need the `when-property-is` rule.

Your `replace-with` looks correct *as long as* it is listed *after* your `inherits` statements. For this reason, I always encourage developers to list all `inherits` rules first, and then go on to any `replace-with` and `generate-with` or `set-property` rules.

For more detail than that, you'll need to post something a little more concrete.

Comment: Thanks! This is the information I was lacking: "last one wins!"

Comment: Same rules apply for `set-property` and `set-configuration-property` rules - later rules win, so you can always override settings already set once.